# partial command output to new command

Tags: bash, terminal

I am trying to automate the following commands in a batch script,
But not sure how to take the [process id] from the [proc_status] to the kill command?

I tried $(!!) and $(1) without success.

```
user1@dev_server_100:/path> ./proc_status
PROC_NAME up, process id = 16394
user1@dev_server_100:/path> kill -9 16394
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overall technique you want is called command-substitution. You can have cmd-sub using `var=$(echo "something) ; echo $var`, or you may find in legacy code where the `$(` and `)` replaced on both sides with the back-tic character (var=`'`echo "something"`'` (Bad formatting here, but S.O. uses backtics for its own purposes. I can't remember how I've made this look right in the past).

Here are several solutions:

```
pidToKill=$( ./proc_status | awk '{print $NF}' )
kill $pidToKill
```

This lets `awk` count the Number of Fields (`NF`) in the line. The `$NF` is read by `awk` as "the value of `$6`" (`NF==6`) in this case.

If the output of `./proc_status` will never change, then you can use a smaller utility to capture the PID, i.e.

```
pidToKill=$( ./proc_status | cut -d " " -f 6 )

kill $pidToKill
```

This `cut`s the 6th field of the output data.

Finally, you can use the shell parameter substitution features to accomplish the same,

```
pidToKill=$( ./proc_status)
kill ${pidToKill##* }
```

The `##*` (A trailing space is needed) says, search the value of `pidToKill` for the up to the last space in the value, and delete everything from the front to that point.

---

You should research why it is a bad thing to use `kill -9` unless absolutely necessary. (Not a good habit to get into. If you know for certain that for this case `-9` is the only solution, then you might want to include a comment in your code about why you are using `-9`.)